# What is the Gain, Input and Output Impedence in this circuit?

Tags: resistors, parallel, series, input-impedance

So I'm trying to know what the input, output impedence and gain is in this circuit

[image: The Circuit in question]

To begin, I'm kind of confused since I don't know if those two resistors at the right are in series or in parallel.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: No it is not, this is one of the exercices I did in class, but I didn't understand completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an ideal op-amp the input is infinite impedance- like it isn't there. So Vin is effectively just connected to two resistors of value 'R'.

Comment: Oh ok I forgot about this criteria!
Can I ask other questions? I'll edit the title and this comment afterward. (I'm new to this website)

The question is about finding the gain ( Vin/Vout ) 
So I know that the tension divider, will gill us Vin/2 so now we know the value of Vin+ and Vin- since it's an ideal Op-Amp
Also that the tension between 6R and 3R is Vout
How do I find the tension in the node surrounded by 8R 6R and 11R?

Comment: You know Vin/2 is at the inverting input. So the current through the resistor to ground must be Vin/(2R). That should easily tell you the voltage at the node you mention, and the output voltage is 1/3 of that. The voltage at the output of the op-amp is unimportant in this problem (in a more realistic problem it might be because the op-amp could saturate).

Comment: Oh yes, so the tension across the 11R resistor will be (11/2)*Vin. Then I sum the tensions, I'll get 6Vin at that node. 
Then I use the tension divider to get the relation between Vout and Vin. It's Vout = 2*Vin
(Yes, I'm currently beginning to learn about Vsat and other important points of Op-Amps!)
My last question would be about the output impedence?

Answer (score 0):

One rule you can go by to know what the input impedance is to ask yourself what the current is through the input? How much is it?

Impedance is directly related to the current through the input (because V = I*R)

So looking at the diagram again, where is the current going? How much?

You could even calculate the input impedance by only knowing the voltage which is Vin and the current through R (we'll call it I) \$V_{in}/I_{R}= Impedance_{in} \$ .

Answer (score 0):

Opamp input impedance is assumed to be infinite - so the 2 resistors at the input (in series) as all the input 'sees' => input resistance is 2R

The 8R can be considered to be part or the opamp due to being inside the feedback loop (so consider it a short) - so gain due to opamp is 12 (1 + 11R/R)
Gain due to the 6R and 3R will be 3 / (3+6) = 1/3
- So overall gain is 4

Now consider the - input to have infinite impedance, and the opamp output impedence (including the 8R) is effectively zero, so the output resistance will be 3R and 6R in parallel => 2R

Comment: So since Vin- has an infinite impedance, it would mean that the current is 0 so we can just ignore that wire. Concerning the Op-Amp output impedence, it's zero so we ignore the 8R resistance. But why didn't we take into account the 11R and R resistance here?

Comment: So I decided to use the Thevenin Theorem and I took the tension across 11R + R as a source of tension. We then have Vth = Vout = 2 Vin. Then to find the Rth we kill the independant source we have then 6R and 3R in Parallel. So Rth = 2R. This is our output Impedance.

Answer (score 0):

Input Impedance:

Is 2R, since it's just the series combination of the two single R valued resistors connected to the positive input of the op-amp (you assume the input impedance of of the op amp inputs themselves is infinite for an ideal op-amp).

Output Impedance:

Looking back from the output, and again assuming the ideal op-amp characteristics of infinite input terminal impedance and zero output terminal impedance.  Take 11R and R in series for 12R, and this is in parallel with 8R for a combined impedance of 4.8R.  This is in series with 6R for a total of 10.8R.  This is then in parallel with 3R for a total output impedance of roughly 2.348R.

Gain:

You need to find the overall Vout/Vin, not just the gain of the op-amp.  to make the math easier, assume 2V at Vin, which then puts 1V at the positive input of the op-amp.  As an ideal op-amp, it will strive to make it's negative input 1V as well, so the voltage at the negative input is now set to 1V.  For this to be 1V, the node at the top of the 11R resistor would have to be at 12V.  This 12V would divide divide across the 3R and 6R to make Vout 4V.  Since the input that was assumed was 2V, and the output is 4V, Vout/Vin is then 2.  So the overall gain of the circuit is 2.